# Mongoose Error 'uri' parameter must be a string got undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

Whenever I try to run node index.js, I am getting "Error [MongooseError]: The `uri` parameter to `openUri()` must be a string, got "undefined". Make sure the first parameter to `mongoose.connect()` or `mongoose.createConnection()` is a string"

Also, index.js and .env are in the same directory.

index.js:

```
const express = require('express');
require('dotenv').config();
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const routes = require('./routes/api');
const path = require('path');


const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

mongoose.connect(process.env.DB, { useNewUrlParser: true })
  .then(() => console.log(`Database connected successfully`))
  .catch(err => console.log(err));

mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;


app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
  next();
});

app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use('/api', routes);

app.use((err, req, res, next) => {
  console.log(err);
  next();
});


app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server running on port ${port}`)
});
```

.env:

```
NODE_ENV = development
PORT = 3000
MONGO_URI = mongodb+srv://"User":1@cluster0.da5tj.mongodb.net/myFirstDatabase?retryWrites=true&w=majority
```

Comment: Where is `process.env.DB` defined?

Comment: In node_modules/dotenv/Readme: const db = require('db')
db.connect({
  host: process.env.DB_HOST,
  username: process.env.DB_USER,
  password: process.env.DB_PASS
})

Comment: It is only in index

Answer (score 0):

You are having just a little error here but here is the fix, your `.env` stores your connection string as `MONGO_URI` and your main code is calling `process.env.DB` which causes the mongoose error you are getting, i have run your code with my db and its working fine your code should be like below without changing your `.env` file

```
const express = require('express');
require('dotenv').config();
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const routes = require('./routes/api');
const path = require('path');


const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGO_URI, { useNewUrlParser: true })
  .then(() => console.log(`Database connected successfully`))
  .catch(err => console.log(err));

mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;


app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
  next();
});

app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use('/api', routes);

app.use((err, req, res, next) => {
  console.log(err);
  next();
});


app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server running on port ${port}`)
});
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to change anything. Still the same error

Comment: i think you should log `process.env` to see if your environment variables are properly define and please can you share your mongoose version ?

Answer (score 0):

I was having same issue and this worked for me. Require in dotenv.

```
require('dotenv').config()
```

...and setting the .env file with variable MONGO_URI = my database connection

...and finally making sure to pass the following into mongoose.connect:

```
process.env.MONGO_URI
```

Hope that helps. I am noob, so don't count on me being able to answer many questions.